# How do I prevent this loop? C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and stack overflow in general so please excuse me if a make a mistake somewhere.
I posted my code down below, but my issue is that when I type either `yes` or `no` at after the calculation is complete, `no` is supposed to end the program (which I was still working on) and `yes` is supposed to set it up for another calculation.

However I end up with a glitchy loop.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool b;
    bool yes = b;
    do {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float a;
        cout << "Enter The amount you are investing:" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter the rate:" << endl;
        cin >> y;
        cout << "Enter the investment period (years):" << endl;
        cin >> z;
        cout << "Enter the compounding period:" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cout << pow((1 + y / a), (a*z))*x << endl << "Want to do another? (yes/no)";
        cin >> b;
        cin.ignore();

    } while (yes = true); {
        cin.clear();
        if (b = yes) {
        }
        else {
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Use `==` for comparison, not `=`. See `if (b = yes)`, for example.

Comment: Same issue as @Ajay said found at `while (yes = true);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not change the original, initial code.

Comment: Explicit comparing a `bool` is bad style. Just use `while ( yes )`. (Better change the name to e.g. `redo`, `once_more`, etc.)

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `do { ... } while ( ... ); { ... }`?

Comment: wow, I wasn't entirely expecting so many replies so soon. I wanted it to make it so the code could beak off if someone didn't want to do another equation

Comment: Okay, good. From your indentation/formatting style it seemed almost like you expected the `while` to interact with the second curly brace block in a special way. Just wanted to be sure you didn't have a misunderstanding there.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of your code is probably due to:

- unintentional reassignment of the termination condition `bool` value: `yes` to: `true`, instead of checking its value, which is done with `==`, not with the assignment `=`.
- no modification of the value `yes` within the `while` loop.

A possible update is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // initialise the sentinel
    bool yes = true;

    do {
        // define variables
        float x, y, z, a;

        // read input
        cout << "Enter The amount you are investing:" << endl;
        cin >> x;
        cout << "Enter the rate:" << endl;
        cin >> y;
        cout << "Enter the investment period (years):" << endl;
        cin >> z;
        cout << "Enter the compounding period:" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cout << pow((1 + y / a), a * z) * x << endl;

        // redo calculation or exit
        cout << "Want to do another? (yes/no)";
        cin >> yes;

        // check termination condition
    } while (yes == true);

    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, watch out for the uninitialised variables: `x`, `y`, `z`, `a` and think for a proper default value that will indicate possible wrong result.

Lastly, withing the calculation: `1 + y / a` is ambiguous, it could mean both: `(1 + y) / a` and: `1 + (y / a)`, put parentheses to enforce precedence in the wanted order.

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying the value of variable `yes`. It is always set to `true`.